# extract dates and times from string in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a column like the one below. The last two sets of numbers are date and time. I want to create date-time column by extracting values from the column.

> 1002206391240385-sponsoredProducts-SameDayPull-20190627-012313.json

The started by extracting the date but it does not give what I need

```
Select regexp_substr('1002206391240385-sponsoredProducts-SameDayPull-20190627-012313.json','-[\\d{8}]-')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This substring extracts the date time part from your string.

```
SELECT substring(col_name,regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-')-1)+1,
                 regexp_instr(col_name,'.json',1)-regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-')-1)-1)
```

`regexp_count` counts have many hyphens in the string

`regexp_instr` gives the position of the hyphen

`substring` returns starting from *second to last hyphen* till *.json* in the string

To test I have used

```
WITH test(col_name) AS (
SELECT '1002206391240385-sponsoredProducts-SameDayPull-20190627-012313.json'::TEXT
)
SELECT col_name,
substring(col_name,regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-')-1)+1,
                  regexp_instr(col_name,'.json',1)-regexp_instr(col_name,'-',1,regexp_count(col_name,'-')-1)-1) datetime
FROM test
```

Output is

```
col_name                                                            datetime
1002206391240385-sponsoredProducts-SameDayPull-20190627-012313.json 20190627-012313
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, and if the filename format is consistent, you could use a non-regex solution e.g. extract the part of the filename string that contains the date and then use [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html) with a [format string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html) to extract the date and time:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(RIGHT('1002206391240385-sponsoredProducts-SameDayPull-20190627-012313.json', 20), 'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS.json')  AS extracted_datetime
```

which returns

```
extracted_datetime    |
----------------------|
2019-06-27 01:23:13+00|
```